# Multiple Functions in a Single Button

Tags: android

I have a google map project, and I am wondering how I would be able to change to different map types using a single button click.

For Example:
At the first time run of app, the map type is NORMAL, then when I tap on the button it will change to TERRAIN, then when I tap on the button again it will change to HYBRID, and when I tap on the button again it will change to NORMAL.

It seems kinda easy when you think about it, but I don't know how will I approach it, how would it be done? Thanks in advance for the help! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an integer as counter increasing every time you click the button and after that use a switch statement to check which map type to toggle. Use modulus to set counter to zero after the last item is switched.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use a static variable:

```
public void onClick(View v){
    static int currMode=NORMAL;
    currMode=currMode==NORMAL?TERRAIN:currMode==TERRAIN?HYBRID:NORMAL;
    map.mode=currMode;
}
```

Or get the maps mode to substitute the static variable(I'm not sure if it can be obtained):

```
public void onClick(View v){
    int currMode=map.mode;
    currMode=currMode==NORMAL?TERRAIN:currMode==TERRAIN?HYBRID:NORMAL;
    map.mode=currMode;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir for the help, I have used a counter to count the number of clicks to change the map type. But thank you for help sir! :D